# Attempted to close an element that was not open

Tags: html, svelte

I've got the following code in Svelte. It works without the `<p>` tag, but when I put the `{#if}...{/if}` inside a `<p>` tag, I receive the following error on the last line and the application doesn't compile.

*< /p> attempted to close an element that was not open*

```
<p>
   <h3>Active games</h3>
   {#if !Array.isArray(games)}
      <span>Loading...</span>
   {:else if games.length === 0}
      <span>None</span>
   {:else}
      {#each games as game (game.id)}
         <a href={'/game/' + game.id}>{game.name}</a><br>
      {/each}
   {/if}
</p>
```

What's causing the error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p,
The "Tag omission" section, `p` tag is automatically closed if encounter any other block level element, eg `<h3>` tag in this example.

In other words, you can't have any other block level element within `<p>` tag.